# How to view/Delete any particular users data in Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am using google Analytics in my Android App. But is there any way I can make to the user delete/View his data which is collected by Google analytics?

This requirement is due to GDPR which requires the data controller which is me in my case to provide the user certain Data Subject Rights which include view/delete their data.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete user's data by following this url below User Deletion API.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/reference/userDeletion/userDeletionRequest#resource

Comment: Thanks For the answer. I hope this works for Android. Can you please try to answer this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429448/how-to-download-data-from-admob

Comment: Also is it possible to anonymize personal information tracking totally in GA?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can delete user data from GA >> Analysis >> User Explorer

Once deletion is requested, data associated with this user identifier will be removed from the Individual User Report within 72 hours, and then deleted from Analytics servers during the next deletion process. Deletion processes are scheduled to occur approximately every two months.

[image: User Explorer]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.